# java if trouble sharing names variables

Tags: java

The code below works. Problem is I have a bunch more if's to write. Is it a way I can "save" the loan sum and put it outside the {} ? After this I am supposed to ask "how much do you earn". is it a way I can write (loan + earn) once or do I have to do it separately to each if?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("is it a full loan?");
    String second = keyboard.next();

    {
        if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            int loan = 8000;
            System.out.println(loan);
        }
    }

    if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("how much do you get");
        int loan = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(loan);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make `loan` visible outside its' assignment block. Second, use an `else`. That should be something like -

```
String second = keyboard.next();
int loan = 0
if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
  loan = 8000;
} else {
  System.out.println ("how much do you get");
  loan = keyboard.nextInt(); 
}
System.out.println(loan);
```

Comment: What if an error is needed if the user says "true", "affirmative", or something other than "yes" that isn't "no"?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Sounds like an *opportunity* for user training, documentation and/or UI work to me! OP's post included two options - yes/no (seems like a good place for an `else` to me).

Comment: My point was simply that the if...else really needs to be refactored, so that you are operating on the result of a conversion to boolean that could, for example, reprompt for input rather than on the output of the .equalsIgnoreCase().

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable outside of the "if" statement. However, a better approach, stylistically speaking, is to use a subroutine with an early return and then assign this to your variable:

```
int loan = promptForLoan();

// ...


private static int promptForLoan() {
   boolean isFullLoan = promptForBoolean("Is it a full loan?");
   if (isFullLoan) {
     return FULL_LOAN_AMOUNT;
   }

   return promptForInt("How much did you get?");
}

// ...
```

You should continue breaking these down into smaller subroutines so that each function does only a very small amount of work (perhaps one or two "if" or loop statements, one or two conversions, etc.)